# Problema al importar modulo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

Tengo dos archivos JavaScript desde el cual en uno quiero consumir una función de otro pero me aparecen errores y no me sirve

En mi archivo sesion.js tengo la siguiente lógica, a este archivo en el HTML desde el que lo llamo le puese la propiedad type="module"

```
//sesion.js
import { reserveCar } from `./Requests`;

function menuOptionsByTypeClient() {
  return reserveCar;

}
```

Ya desde Request.js

```
export function reserveCar() {
  console.log("Hola");
  return `<p> HOLA</p>`;
}
```

y lo único que me muestra el navegador es

```
// Uncaught SyntaxError: missing module specifier after 'from' keyword
```

De ninguna manera he logrado que me traiga el código o que me muestre por consola ese "hola", estoy en firefox y he intentado con Chrome y tampoco me sirve

Esa función la tengo ligada a la lógica dentro de un botón que incluso cuando exporto la función deja de aparecer el botón

[image: Botón el cual el archivo sesion.js se encarga de manejar la lógica]

Comment: Parece que te falta especificar la extension del archivo `import { reserveCar } from './Requests.js';` de acuerdo a la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: Parece que no estás exportando la funcion del fichero sesion.js

Comment: ¿Son tus archivos servidos por un servidor web o estás trabajando de forma local directamente?